# getBaseContext() and getApplicationContext()

Tags: android, android-context

In the following code, there is an error in `getBaseContext()` and `getApplicationContext()`,
both of them are red in color.

Does anyone know how to solve them? Moreover, I also want to know when to use these two methods. I have searched in internet, but I didn't understand. Can anyone simply explain something about these two methods? I am new in java.

```
public class calendar1 extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar_menu);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addevent);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new addevent());
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showcalendar);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new showcalendar());
    }

    private class addevent implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
            intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
            intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
            intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
            intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

    private class showcalendar implements View.OnClickListener{

        public void onClick(View v){

            String[] projection = new String[] { CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION };

            // 0 = January, 1 = February, ...

            Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            startTime.set(2014,00,01,00,00);

            Calendar endTime= Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.set(2015,00,01,00,00);

            // the range is all data from 2014

            String selection = "(( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " >= " + startTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ) AND ( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " <= " + endTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ))";

            Cursor cursor = this.getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query( CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null );

            // output the events

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Title: " + cursor.getString(1) + " Start-Time: " + (new Date(cursor.getLong(3))).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } while ( cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use `calendar1.this` instead of those methods

Comment: I would assume that it does not only mark methods red, but also writes some error, does it? Anyway the case is simple - `this` keyword in your case refers to shocalendar instance which does not have `getBaseContext` method. So you will have to write `calendar1.this`. Andr don't use getBaseContext, just omit this call since Activity is also a ContextWrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following context to solve your problem

```
calendar1.this
```

To explain why you are getting that error in the first place. You are using

`this.getBaseContext()` and `this.getApplicationContext()` inside the `showcalendar`, which is a `View.OnClickListener` class, as you can see from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html), it does not have those methods.

Comment: Just to explain: in `showcalendar`, `this` refers to itself (`showcalendar`), not `calendar1` the Activity ;)